# Merging of Two Questions

Tags: support, questions

Recently [How to make Martian soil](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-make-martian-soil), was posted on this site and it has two answers.

[The same question was posted on SE Space Exploration](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19032/how-to-make-martian-soil), where it received one answer and was migrated to our site. Now our site has two identical questions.

I think these two question need to be merged, but I do not know how that is done. Could someone who knows how to do this please merge the two questions.

Comment: It is possible that marking one as duplicate of the other is the first step. Once one is closed as a duplicate, I have a hunch that it is more straightforward for a moderator to merge. I've made their tags identical and voted to close the Space SE (migrated) copy as duplicate of the Earth Science copy. There's now a [comment by a Space mod](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19032/how-to-make-martian-soil#comment41712_19032) recommending merging.

Answer (score 1):

I have [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) the questions.  Merging can only be done by diamond moderators, so flagging for moderator attention (which someone did) was the right course of action here.